# Mailchimp API /lists date type parameter formatting for merge_fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a `date` merge_field that I need to populate in the v3 version of the Mailchimp API. Lots of google searching on this before I found my answer... hopefully this saves someone time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format expected is: `mm/dd/yyyy`.

It appears that single digits in month and day work just fine so don't sweat making it strict. If you're in Javascript passing a date object into this function should work for you (assuming you're okay with using the local timezone):

```
function mailchimpDateFormat(date) {
  return date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
}
```

So in node.js for example a call to the Mailchimp v3 API would look like this:

```
mailchimp.put({
  "path": "/lists/0564f2d799/members/c5f129f4bac9d1ca985cb58f1f45f24",
  "body": {
    "email_address": "something@company.com",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "interests": {
      "ca1564ff8f": true
    },
    "merge_fields": {
      "MY_DATE": mailchimpDateFormat(date) // e.g. "4/15/2018"
    }
  }
}, function (err, response) {
   // Do something interesting.
};
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Just what I was looking for.